# Using GLEW and GLM on Mac with CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, cmake, glm-math

I am unsure as to why I am greeted with "fatal error: 'GL/glew.h' file not found" when trying to build. My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(ex_1)

add_executable(TorusDraw.out TorusDraw.cpp)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(GLM REQUIRED)

include_directories( ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}  ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLM_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

target_link_libraries( TorusDraw.out ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${GLEW_LIBRARY} ${GLM_LIBRARY} )
```

It looks as though it also cannot find glm

[Image showing CLion not recognising glm and GLEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqkZX.png)

Edit: I should mention the libraries were installed with homebrew

Comment: Please add the minimal source code that is not compiling, and the exact error log including the command line of the compiler command.

Comment: Does using `find_package(glm REQUIRED)` (lowercase "glm") make a difference?

Comment: generally you do not need GLEW when running on mac. There's some uses for it but generally it is for loading function pointers to the opengl functions that are supplied by drivers. But because apple creates the hardware and software, they kinda deal with this for you. try removing everything glew and see what happens